# How can I make CSS grid left column fit the number of rows

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm dynamically creating a grid layout. My goal is to have the column on the left always be the same as the height of the rows. I've gotten it to work for 2+ rows, but it breaks if there is only a single row.

Here's my CSS:

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3rem 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 3rem;
    background-color: grey;
}

.left-side {
    background-color: blue;
    grid-column: 1 / 1;
    grid-row: 1 / span 1000;
}

.row {
    background-color: lightblue;
    border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="row">Bad!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="row">Good!</div>
    <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="row">Good!</div>
    <div class="row">Good!</div>
    <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `grid-row: span 2` to `.row`

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3rem 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 3rem;
  background-color: grey;
}

.left-side {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1000;
}

.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: solid red 1px;
  grid-row: span 2;
}

/* fix for a small bug. you can see by removing */
.row:nth-last-of-type(n+2) {
  grid-row: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`position:absolute` seems suitable here

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  padding-left:3rem;
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 3rem;
  background-color: grey;
  position:relative;
}

.left-side {
  background-color: blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:3rem;
}

.row {
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>

<br>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="left-side"></div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
  <div class="row">Good!</div>
</div>
```